# style error while running odoo-11 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, odoo-11, erp

I'm running odoo 11.0 on ubuntu 18.04, when starting the server the website doesn't appear properly and I got this error:

```
Style error

The style compilation failed, see the error below. Your recent actions may be the cause, please try reverting the changes you made.

(b'', b'The "--no-js" argument is deprecated, as inline JavaScript is disabled by default. Use "--js" to enable inline JavaScript (not recommended).
ParseError: Unrecognized input. Possibly missing '(' in mixin call. in - on line 1314, column 29:
1313 .o-caret-down(@caret-width: @caret-width-base) {
1314     .utils-caret-boilerplate;
1315     border-bottom: 0;

')This error occured while compiling the bundle 'web.assets_common' containing:
    - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/less/variables.less
    - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/less/mixins/vendor-prefixes.less
    - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/less/mixins/buttons.less
    - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/less/mixins/clearfix.less
    - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/less/mixins/size.less
    - /web/static/src/less/variables.less
    - /web/static/src/less/utils.less
    - /web_editor/static/src/less/web_editor.variables.less
    - /web/static/lib/bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/less/_bootstrap-datetimepicker.less
    - /web/static/src/less/fonts.less
    - /web/static/src/less/navbar.less
    - /web/static/src/less/mimetypes.less
    - /web/static/src/less/modal.less
    - /web/static/src/less/animation.less
    - /web/static/src/less/rainbow.less
    - /web/static/src/less/datepicker.less
    - /web_planner/static/src/less/web_planner_common.less
    - /web_tour/static/src/less/tip.less
    - /web_tour/static/src/less/keyframes.less
```

I was running on node v12.8.3 and tried to downgrade to v10.5.0 but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 19):

I solved this problem downgrading the version of less.

I had less@4:

```
$ lessc --version
lessc 4.0.0 (Less Compiler) [JavaScript]
```

Uninstalled less:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g less
```

Installed less@3.10.3:

```
sudo npm install -g less@3.10.3
```

And it's working now. I hope it is useful.

Comment: Thanks, its helps me to solve issue with odoo 11 on Apple M1. resolved after 2 days of searching.

Answer (score 0):

*Try this*

```sh
sudo apt install python3-libsass
```